# Can't update an image from the bucket

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I've been trying to update a single file within a folder in the bucket that i created but when i go to update with a new image from the front does not update the image and gives the following error.
`statusCode: "404", error: "Not found"`
Then when i went to check the route of the call it seems to be wrong `http://localhost:54321/storage/v1/object/xxx-images/xxx_image/36a75358-8612-4e0e-96d8-76e4f579b80d.jpg`. So after checked the route i went to the bucket and copy the route from the image uploaded and the route is different from the route of the call previously mentioned `http://localhost:54321/storage/v1/object/public/xxx-images/xxx_image/05f9d208-bab2-45ab-a355-71ba4a41cf59.jpg`.
As you can see the route from the image saved on the bucket has the `/public/` word on the route. I took the api call to update from the documentation [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/v1/storage-from-update) and the api call on the front that i have made is the following:

```
     const { data, error } = await supabase
      .storage
      .from('xxx-images')
      .update(`xxx_image/${oldPresentationImage}`, presentationImage.file, {
        contentType: 'image/png'
      });
    if(error) {console.log('error ', error)};
```

I don't get why the route is not the same when i call the api update method from the front.  I'm using the version `1.1.0` and i got the policies for `authenticated users`

Answer (score 1):

The `public` keyword in the URL of your uploaded image just means that it's the public URL of the image.

The documentation is correct, and you do not need a `public` keyword inside of your code for updating.

The issue probably here is that you don't have `select` policy set for your storage.objects table. As the [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/v1/storage-from-update) says, you need both update and select permission to perform `update` call.

> objects permissions: update and select

Comment: Thanks for the response. I’m only having the problem that the image file name is only updating on the db but is not updating on the bucket, I keeps the same old name but the image changed

Comment: If you want to change the name of the image, `update()` would not work. `update()` is used to update the meta data and stuff for an existing image. If you want to change the image name or image location, you want to use `move()`. https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-move

Comment: Maybe I can keep the same file name and change the meta data, but I had to open a incognito window to see the change of image